# How to change color of only one tableviewcell textlable.text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView I have 7 tableviewcell,i just want to change textcolor of 5th cell.Is it possible?

I tried Static cell but it wont work for me cause i only want one cell.textlable.textcolor change not othercell.

Comment: if you're using static cells you can set the color in storyboards directly

Comment: Hey i got the answer...i used the below code.--------if([cell.m_mainListLbl.text isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {
        cell.m_mainListLbl.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
        return cell;
    }

Comment: If you have got the answer, why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Something like this

```
if(indexPath.row==4)
{
     yourCell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor redColor];
}

else 
{ 
    yourCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Comment: not background color ,i want to change textcolor.Thanks for help.

Comment: I changed it. My answer is correct . Please accept my answer

Comment: This will cause problems. You need to add `else { yourCell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; }`. Without that, as you scroll your table view, other cells will appear with the red text.

Comment: Also the 5th cell will have a indexpath.row of 4 ;)

Answer (score 0):

`if([cell.m_mainListLbl.text isEqualToString:@"Logout"])
    {
    cell.m_mainListLbl.textColor=[UIColor redColor]; return cell;
    }`

I used this code.
It Works for me.

Comment: This will cause problems. You need to add `else { cell.m_mainListLabl.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; }`. Without that, as you scroll your table view, other cells will appear with the red text.